# One java standalone application taking more time for execution in Oracle Solaris 11.4 OS which takes 3 times less time in Red Hat Linux server

Tags: java, linux, networking, solaris

One java standalone application taking more time for execution in Oracle Solaris 11.4 OS which takes 3 times less time in Red Hat Linux server. What can be the issue? The code is exactly the same.

Comment: It could be many things.  CPU core performance.  Number of cores.  Available memory.  Memory system performance.  Disk or network speed.  Operating system.  File system. Other things running on the server.  Different Java versions.  And so on.

Comment: Can you please tell me how I going to figure out what actually causes the program to take this much of time? Thanks in advance. @ Stephen C

Comment: Have you compared the hardware?

Comment: I'm not so sure this question should have been migrated here from superuser.com.  There's no clear coding issue to address, performance or otherwise.  You'll have to provide a lot more detail about your application - what does it do?  How does it do it?  You'll probably have to provide a lot of system performance data comparing running the app on both systems.  You'll have to provide specifics on both servers - RAM, CPU, disk drive(s) and disk controller(s).  As is, there's really no way to provide any answer.

Comment: Hi, previously it was on Linux. Here is the details-


JAVA_VERSION="1.8.0_121"
OS_NAME="Linux"
OS_VERSION="2.6"
OS_ARCH="amd64"
BUILD_TYPE="commercial"

Later on, it migrated on Sun Os. Here are the details -

JAVA_VERSION="1.7.0"
OS_NAME="SunOS"
OS_VERSION="5.10"
OS_ARCH="sparcv9"
BUILD_TYPE=commercial


What could be the reason so that the application is taking 3x more time in this server?


@stephen C

Comment: My bet is that the hardware is slower.   But you are also using an older version of Java.

Comment: Again, you need to provide the actual hardware you're running the comparisons on.  "sparcv9" dates back to 1993, and "amd64" dates back to 2003.

Comment: sparcv9 processor speed = 2.6GHz